# Pcm to decibel conversion in esp-idf using pdm microphone

Tags: esp32, pcm, esp-idf

I am using Pdm microphone with esp32-wroom-32. By using Esp-idf i2s_pdm_rx example i was able to get Pcm data steam in an array buffer from theses int16_t values how can i measure sound pressure.

**I read on esp-idf api guides that this data in converted by esp32 from pdm to pcm. i am not sure about that either if remember correctly someone point out only esp32-s3 can convert pdm to pcm at peripheral stage**

I am new to audio processing dont know much about dsp.

`int16_t *r_buf = (int16_t *)calloc(1, EXAMPLE_BUFF_SIZE);`

`i2s_channel_read(rx_chan, r_buf, EXAMPLE_BUFF_SIZE, &r_bytes, 1000)`

r_buff will get pcm data how can i convert it to decibels sound measurement.

I tried to measure root mean square of this pcm signal than take log but most of the values results in **nan or -inf**

Comment: PDM is not an analog audio signal (at least not directly), it is a digital representative of an audio signal encoded in Pulse Density Modulation. Get an analog mic and feed it into ADC and buffer the ADC outputs to do the decibel calculation.

Comment: what i have understand adc also read analog in pcm format. we can convert pdm to pcm using a filter or do some dsp on signal than calculate decibel but i dont know how to do that